# Setting Integrated mode in web.config for IIS7

Tags: iis-7, web-config

In IIS7 you now have an integrated mode and an classic mode.
Is it possible to force a site to run in integrated mode using web.config and without access to IIS7.

Reason I ask is that I have recently signed up with Mosso and need to run my site in integrated mode and not classic.

I know I can call them and maybe get them to change it over...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a setting you won't be able to change through your app's `web.config`.

The pipeline mode is a property of the application pool and is configured:

> `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

under:

> configuration->system.applicationHost->applicationPools

Answer (score 1):

You also need to be aware that there are new nodes in the web.config for integrated mode.  If you use http headers they need to be moved from system.web to system.webserver.  There are some good articles that discuss this here:  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/registering_the_httphandlers_on_windows_vista_iis_7_integrated_mode.html and here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx