# Configuration in Web.config to run application in a IIS 7+ classic mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Is there any way that I can config in my web.config if customer is using IIS 7+ the application should run in a classic mode.

Thanx

Comment: I think you need to change on server rather in web.config.

Comment: thanx Mohammad, But I dnt want to do that, because it will make other application which are in that app pool to run in classic mode

Answer (score 2):

This setting can't be changed through your application's web.config file. As the application runs under IIS, you have no control over this setting.

Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470374/setting-integrated-mode-in-web-config-for-iis7)

Answer (score 0):

Anwer to your comment "because it will make other application which are in that app pool to run in classic mode"

That is not necessary. You can configure multipe application pools: one for "classic" and one or more for the rest.

Comment: Thanx, I know but  it will be another work load,if I have to create a an additional app pool I will create one with classic mood and will host in that app pool :)